# Affect 'cousin' element purely using css

Tags: css

I have the following html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="I_affect_this">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Want_to_affect_this_also">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried the following hoping that would work although I also understand why it does not:

```
.I_affect_this{

}

.Want_to_affect_this_also{

}

//I tried this
.I_affect_this + Want_to_affect_this_also{

}
```

I really want to change that element **only if I_affect_this** exists, therefore this specific rule... does anyone know how this could be done purely with css? Thank you very much for your help...

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. Do you want to apply the same css rules to "I_affect_this" and to "Want_to_affect_this_also" ? If yes, then you can simply do `.I_affect_this, .Want_to_affect_this_also { ... }` .

Comment: Is this exactly the HTML mark-up you are dealing with? If so , you have two `td` elements in the same table, and you want them both to have the same of the same styling rules.  It may not be clear, yet, what you are trying to do.

Comment: If it depends on the very presence of the first td, AND there's nothing else in the first tr, you can use the fact that the first tr is empty or not. In other words, give a class to the first tr and then say `tr.Class_of_the_first_tr:not(:empty)) + tr .Want_to_affect_this_also` for a selector. That's about as close as you can get with pure CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the questions correctly, I am pretty sure there is no way of doing what you want to do with pure CSS.  There doesn't seem to be anywhere in the CSS3 Spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors that would indicate that sort of selector .

Comment: Neither using a combination of selectors? ... :x